# Showing that the Schwarz-Christoffel Integral is a biholomorphic mapping

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I want to show that the Schwarz-Christoffel Integral

$$
I(z)=\int^z_0\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2x^2)}}
$$

is a biholomorphic mapping from the upper half complex plane to the rectangle. If $I$ is injective, then by using the fact that $I$ maps the boundary to the boundary I think I can show that it is surjective. However, I am stuck at how to the integral is injective. Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks!